# Selenium webdriver doesnt detect web dialog window

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, dialog, selenium-webdriver

I am using IE 8 and Webdriver 2.35, Java. In my application when i click a button, it will open a web dialog and i have few texts and buttons to perform actions in the web dialog but webdriver does not detect it at all.

Set availableWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();

//the above code for my application always returns 1 using iterator which means webdriver fails to detect the web dialog.
Is there a work around which i can use it, so that webdriver focus on to the webdialog?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: windowHandles() is used for performing on a new window/tab. If it is just a html dialog(which i am assuming it is) there is no need to switch into that dialog. Share the html code I can help you out.

Comment: Thanks vinay for the response. Here's the code.

Comment: wDriver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit Order")).click();
  wDriver.findElement(By.id("orderNbrFindButton")).click();  
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wDriver, 10);
  
  for(String NewWindowHandle:wDriver.getWindowHandles())
   {
   wDriver.switchTo().window(NewWindowHandle);   //switch to new window 
   }
  
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SearchButton")));
 wDriver.findElement(By.name("SearchButton")).click();
for(String NewWindowHandle:wDriver.getWindowHandles())
   {
   wDriver.switchTo().window(NewWindowHandle);   //switch to new window 
   }

Comment: wDriver1.findElement(By.id("OrderColorsTextBox")).click();
   wDriver1.findElement(By.id("OrderColorsTextBox")).sendKeys("testblue");

 as you see here. there are two dialog boxes 1. when i click on orderNbrFindButton the first dialog opens and this is detected and 2. when i click on Searchbutton the second dialog box opens but it is not detected. Looking for your help Thanks @Vinay

Comment: Please share the html of the page for the dialog. The easiest way to find out if the pop up is html based right click on the pop up. If you get the option for firebug then it is regular html pop up else it is js pop up.

Comment: <!-- BUTTONS & MAIN TITLES -->
<div class="popupHeaderBox">
<div style="height:100px;">
<div style="padding-right:30px; padding-top:20px; float:right; text-align:right;">
<input type="image" name="EditButton" id="EditButton" class="viewCtrl" src="/TextButtonGenerator.ashx?imageUrl=%7e%2fImages%2fButton.png&amp;textColor=215%2c0%2c0%2c0&amp;textFont=Tahoma%2c11%2c1&amp;scalableRectangle=5%2c5%2c75%2c20&amp;text=edit&amp;textPadding=20%2c6" alt="edit" style="background-color:Transparent;border-width:0px;" />

Comment: <input type="image" name="CancelButton" id="CancelButton" class="editCtrl" src="/TextButtonGenerator.ashx?imageUrl=%7e%2fImages%2fButton.png&amp;textColor=215%2c0%2c0%2c0&amp<input type="image" name="CancelButton" id="CancelButton" class="editCtrl" src="/TextButtonGenerator.ashx?imageUrl=%7e%2fImages%2fButton.png&amp;textColor=215%2c0%2c0%2c0&amp;textFont=Tahoma%2c11%2c1&amp;scalableRectangle=5%2c5%2c75%2c20&amp;text=cancel&amp;textPadding=20%2c6" alt="cancel" style="background-color:Transparent;border-width:0px;" />
<br />
</div>

Comment: The above html code is a portion of the web dialog box i am talking about. where i  want to click the edit button to perform some actions on the web dialog window. I get the firebug action as you mentioned @Vinay

Comment: It throws Unable to find such element exception as webdriver is not having issues with the webelement, it is failing to identify the web dialog window itself. As similar web dialog is identified for first window and in second dialog window is not identified. Any help or pointer will be of great help.

Comment: Can you please share the url. Will be of great help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is an internal application. It doesnt work via internet. Am just so wondered as it detects the 1st window dialog but 2nd window dialog is just been ignored or not detected :(

Answer (score 0):

We can handle dialog window by using switch to alert.

```
    alert = _driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept()//for click on ok button
    alert..dismiss();//for cancel button
```

Comment: Thanks Raghu for response. But this is not an alert box. Intially i had an issue with IE alert box but then subsided with following code. ((JavascriptExecutor)wDriver).executeScript("window.open(\"\", \"_self\");window.close();"); But this window dialog is just not detected